# NTFS drive mount

Tags: dual-boot, mount, ntfs

I have both windows 8.1 and ubuntu 14.04 installed on my system.
I was not able to mount my drives in ubuntu but after disabling fast startup in windows it worked perfectly fine.
I recently installed cinnamon shell in my ubuntu and after that i'm not able to mount my windows drive( C:). My D: drive is easily mounted but in case of my C: drive it shows that windows is hibernated and ntfs drive is in unsafe mode.
I tried shutting and restarting windows with both fast startup enabled and disabled but its still no use.
What can i do to mount my C: dive ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to mount Windows (NTFS) filesystem due to hibernation](https://askubuntu.com/questions/145902/unable-to-mount-windows-ntfs-filesystem-due-to-hibernation)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a detailed answer to your problem: [Unable to mount Windows (NTFS) filesystem due to hibernation](https://askubuntu.com/questions/145902/unable-to-mount-windows-ntfs-filesystem-due-to-hibernation)

What i did most of the times, was to open the drive in read only mode as i mostly only copy files from ntfs drives or watch movie from it.

Here is how to do that:

Open the application 'disks utility'. Select the drive on right hand side. chose the volume label that you want to open as read only.

There is a settings icon somewhere below it. click it and select the read-only option.

That should do it.